# Primefaces autocomplete error completeMethod

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a problem with primefaces autocomplete.
The jsf page is as follow :

```
<h:inputText class="form-control" style="" for="villeRecherche"/>
<p:autoComplete id="villeRecherche"
value="#{rechercheRestoMb.selectedVille}"
completeMethod="#{rechercheRestoMb.completeVille}"
converter="convertisseurVille" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.ville}"
itemValue="#{c}" forceSelection="true" required="true" />
```

when the jsf is called I have this server 500 error:

```
javax.el.ELException: /corpsIndex.xhtml: The class 'fr.afcepf.al25.projetResto.managedBean.RechercheRestoMb' does not have the property 'completeVille'.
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

My ManagedBean is RechercheRestoMb and it contains he method completeVille

If I insert public String completeVille with getters and setters I don't have the error but the autocomplete does not work.

Anyone has an idea for this problem?

Comment: can you post your class `rechercheRestoMb` and the method `completeVille`

Comment: Better to ask for an [mcve] (see also: http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info]

Comment: In your post you talk a lot about the bean but you do not post it... why? And just take a look at the PrimeFaces showcase and compare their example with your code. Simple...

Answer (score 2):

> javax.el.ELException: /corpsIndex.xhtml: The class 'fr.afcepf.al25.projetResto.managedBean.RechercheRestoMb' does not have the property 'completeVille'.

This exception means that the EL expression is being interpreted as a property value expression (which requires a getter method), not as a method expression. Basically, it couldn't find the `getCompleteVille()` method. However, you actually shouldn't need one. There's more at matter.

Look closer at the stack trace what happened during rendering:

```
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
```

`UILeaf`>`UIInstructions` is the Facelets representation for EL in template text like so

```
<p>Welcome, #{user.name}</p>
```

This is unexpected as you declared the EL expression in a `<p:autoComplete>` component which should appear as `org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete` in that line. This thus means that the `<p:xxx>` tag library is not recognized and is interpreted as template text and thus remain unparsed during generating the HTML output. In effects, you're sending `<p:autoComplete>` plain vanilla to webbrowser instead of letting JSF generate its HTML output.

This in turn can have several causes, the most common being:

- You didn't install PrimeFaces (just drop JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`).
- You didn't declare its XML namespace (use `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`).